# Magento - call static block when php BodyClass == ‘whatever’

Tags: php, magento

in my 2col-inside.phtml file i can successfully call a block using:
`<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('blue-banner')->toHtml() ?>`

however i would like to serve up a unique banner based on the URI or body class.  so something like:

```
<?php if($bodyClass['category-blue']): ?>  
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('blue-banner')->toHtml() ?>
<?php elseif($bodyClass['category-red']): ?>  
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('red-banner')->toHtml() ?> 
<?php else($bodyClass['category-yellow']): ?>  
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('yellow-banner')->toHtml() ?>  
<?php endif;?>
```

Setting the BlockId to the page url would work too (i'd just have to go back and rename all the blocks to exactly match the page url), but i don't know how to extract JUST the page url either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are these only for category pages? If so, does 'category-blue' refer to a specific category called 'Blue'?

Comment: yes these are category pages.  I wound up using the code below... is there a category specific solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You even don't need to perform any development for displaying the static block on a particular category page or any cms or layout based page. Use Widgets functionality of Magento.

1. Go to "CMS -> Widgets"
2. Press "Add New Widget Instance" button
3. Select widget type (in your case it is "CMS Static Block") and theme where it should be shown. Press "Continue" button.
4. Type in "Widget Instance Title" and select stores where it should be displayed.
5. Press "Add Layout Update" button and select your widget "display on" settings (Categories, Products, CMS Pages, Checkout Pages, etc) and select in wich part of the page you want to show it up.
6. Go to "Widget Options" tab and select static block which you want to show up.

Hope it will help you with your problem without any development :)

Answer (score 0):

not pretty, but this works if you name the static blocks the same as your page name:

```
<?php   $_base_url = $this->helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl();
        $class = str_replace($_base_url, '', $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
        $pagetitle = str_replace('.html', '', $class);
        $page = str_replace('industries/', '', $pagetitle);
?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($page)->toHtml() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this inside your `app/design/frontend/default/<theme>/catalog/catalog/category/view.phtml`:

```
$cat_name = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
$block_name = $cat_name.'-banner';  
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($block_name)->toHtml();
```

Throw some `if` statements in there to check for nulls and you should be away.

Cheers,
JD

Answer (score 0):

In your `2col-inside.phtml` add this where you want the banner.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('banner_block') ?>
```

This is safe because nothing will be echoed if `banner_id` doesn't exist.

For each category where you want the banner edit it's "Custom Layout Update" box to include the following...

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="cms/block" name="banner_block">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>blue_banner</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

...changing the `block_id` as appropriate. The same can also be done on product and CMS pages. If a page is not using `2cols-inside.phtml` template then nothing happen is changed.

Comment: My way is old-fashioned (by several months!) and Ivan's widget method is much nicer. Use that unless the location of the banner is some place awkward.